# Composite Functions - Calculus Homework

Tags: calculus

Find $h(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $f(x) = (h \circ g)(x)$ and

$$f(x) = \sqrt{4x+5}-2$$

Suppose that $g(x) = 4x+3$.

I'm struggling to find the solution as to what h(x) is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you have written is that $f(x)=h(x)\times g(x)=\sqrt {4x+5}-2$.  Is that what you meant?  If so, you can get $h(x)$ by division.  But the header refers to composition, so perhaps you meant to write $f(x)=h\circ g(x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal is to look for a path that takes $g(x) = 4x+3$ into $f(x) = \sqrt{4x+5}-2$.

Step 1: Could $h(x) = \sqrt{x}$? Well, this would give $h(g(x)) = \sqrt{4x+3}$, which is not there yet.

Step 2: Adapt to $h(x) = \sqrt{x} - 2$. Then $h(g(x)) = \sqrt{4x+3} - 2$. Almost there.

Step 3: Finish it! $h(x) = \sqrt{x + 2} - 2$.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was just wondering, how did you go from sqrt(4x + 3) - 2 to h(x) = sqrt(x+2) - 2?

Comment: @Blackthorn Subtracting 2 outside the square root was not enough to get the desired function, since in the inside we should have x+5. Thus, with $h(x) = \sqrt{x+2}-2$ we have $h(g(x)) = \sqrt{g(x)+2} - 2 = \sqrt{4x+3+2} - 2$, solving the problem.

Comment: Huge help! Thanks so much :)